# Linked list code below gives interesting errors,can you check that?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *root = (node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
*root->next = NULL;
void print (node*abc)
{
    while(abc!=NULL)
    {
        printf ("%d",abc->data);
        abc = abc->next;
    }
}
void addTail (node*abc)
{
    while (abc->next!=NULL);
    abc->next = ( node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
}
int main ()
{
printf ("dd");
}
```

The errors i get here are:

7   22      [Error] 'node' undeclared here (not in a function)

7   27      [Error] expected expression before ')' token

8   5       [Error] expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '->' token

In function 'addTail':
23  20  [Error] expected expression before ')' token

In function 'addHead':
28  28      [Error] expected expression before ')' token

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. What works in one does not necessarily work in the other (just like what a british person says does not necessarily get understood by an american person) and vice-versa.

Comment: @pmg yes but it gets confusing because there isnt a proper full code in c for full linked list code and the codes i tried like this does not work even i got the codes from a c lesson video

Comment: I believe the c lesson video you watched is worth less than what you paid for it. I would try to get my money back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
```

created type `struct node`

```
struct node *root = (node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

You cannot have code outside a function. The above line does not belong here, hanging out of any function like that.
Besides that, it tries to convert the return value of the `malloc()` function (of `void*` type) to a pointer to a type that does not exist (type `node` does not exist; type `struct node` exists).
And also, it is, at best redundant and at worse an error, wrong to cast the return value of `malloc()` in C.

```
*root->next = NULL;
```

Again, a statement hanging out of any function. Illegal in C.

```
void print (node*abc)
```

Type `node` does not exist, you can't use pointers to types that do not exist.

```
{
    while(abc!=NULL)
    {
        printf ("%d",abc->data);
        abc = abc->next;
    }
}
void addTail (node*abc)
```

Type `node` does not exist, you can't use pointers to types that do not exist.

```
{
    while (abc->next!=NULL);
    abc->next = ( node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
}
int main ()
{
printf ("dd");
}
```

Have fun!

Comment: Well this was helpful , plus i fortunately didn't pay anything for the video ;)

Comment: hehe that makes the video have negative value! :D If you want to learn C (or any subject), don't watch negative valued videos!!